# GeoJSON / mongoose-geojson-schema / intro confusion

Tags: mongoose, geojson, hapi.js

Newbie question and confusion as I am trying to learn Hapi / Mongoose / Mongo.

Tasked myself with wanting to simply create a model/object that contains text and a geolocation Point ( lat & lon ) and can retrieve these objects from the DB with a supplied current lat & lon

Trying to create a schema using mongoose-geojson-schema package

`"mongoose": "^4.11.1",
"mongoose-geojson-schema": "^2.1.2"`

Model:

```js
const GeoJSON = require('mongoose-geojson-schema');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Point = mongoose.Schema.Types.Point

const postModel = new Schema({
  _owner: { type: String, ref: 'User' },
  text: { type: String },
  loc: Point
});
```

Create Post:

```
let post = new Post();
post._owner = req.payload.user_id;
post.text = req.payload.text;

var point = new GeoJSON({
  point: {
  type: "Point",
  coordinates: [req.payload.lat, req.payload.lon]
  }
})
post.loc = point
```

Keep getting the error `GeoJSON is not a constructor` in the logs.  Tried different variations and have gotten other errors like `loc: Cast to Point failed for value "{ type: 'Point', coordinates: [ '39.0525909', '-94.5924078' ] }" at path "loc"`

Answer (score 2):

I have found the mongoose-geojson-schema package a nuisance to use. If you are simply storing a point, change your model to:

```
const postModel = new Schema({
  _owner: { type: String, ref: 'User' },
  text: { type: String },
  loc: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [Number]
  }
});
```

Next, you are storing your coordinates backward. Although we typically think of lat/lon, in the GIS world we think lon/lat. GeoJson is no different. Think of it in x/y terms and it will make sense. So change your creation to:

```
post.loc = {
  type: 'Point',
  coordinates: [req.payload.lon, req.payload.lat]
}
```

At this point it will store in mongo correctly, but it won't be of much use because you won't be able to search or do any math on it. The last thing you need to do is add a 2dsphere index.

```
postModel.index({'loc': '2dsphere'});
```

Now you should be good to go. You can find posts within a given distance of a point:

```
postModel.find({
  loc:{
    $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ -105.42559,36.55685 ], 10 ] }
  }
}).exec()
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up going this way too!